# echo partial text

Tags: php

I want to display just two lines of the paragraph.
How do I do this ?

```
<p><?php if($display){ echo $crow->content;} ?></p>
```

Comment: you need to be more specific.

Comment: you can take the help of illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $crow->content, 3);
echo $lines[0] . '<br />' . $lines[1];
```

and for variable number of lines, use:

```
$num_of_lines = 2;
$lines = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $crow->content, $num_of_lines+1);
array_pop($lines);
echo implode('<br />', $lines);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the textual content you are referring to, you might be able to get away with this :

```
// `nl2br` is a function that converts new lines into the '<br/>' element.
$newContent = nl2br($crow->content);

// `explode` will then split the content at each appearance of '<br/>'.
$splitContent = explode("<br/>",$newContent);

// Here we simply extract the first and second items in our array.
$firstLine = $splitContent[0];
$secondLine = $splitContent[1];
```

**NOTE** - This will destroy all the line breaks you have in your text!  You'll have to insert them again if you still want to preserve the text in its original formatting.

Comment: @zol - This is what the `nl2br()` function does.  [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), it says it will work on `\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r`

Comment: @zol - if you read my answer again you'll see that I **did** note that point :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sentences you are able to do this by exploding the paragraph and selecting the first two parts of the array:

```
$array = explode('.', $paragraph);
$2lines = $array[0].$array[1];
```

Otherwise you will have to count the number of characters across two lines and use a substr() function. For example if the length of two lines is 100 characters you would do:

```
$2lines = substr($paragraph, 0, 200);
```

However due to the fact that not all font characters are the same width it may be difficult to do this accurately. I would suggest taking the widest character, such as a 'W' and echo as many of these in one line. Then count the maximum number of the largest character that can be displayed across two lines. From this you will have the optimum number. Although this will not give you a compact two lines, it will ensure that it can not go over two lines.

This is could, however, cause a word to be cut in two. To solve this we are able to use the explode function to find the last word in the extracted characters.

```
$array = explode(' ', $2lines);
```

We can then find the last word and remove the correct number of characters from the final output.

```
$numwords = count($array);
$lastword = $array[$numwords];
$numchars = strlen($lastword);
$2lines = substr($2lines, 0, (0-$numchars));
```

Comment: Yep - wanted to remove my vote, but splitting on the "." character is also a problem.  What if the string `Dr.Love` is contained within the text?

Comment: That's why I suggest using a substr instead.

Comment: Using `substr` might result in an unwanted situation of cutting a word in two.  I removed my vote because your answer *is* valid.  However is is not very robust.

Comment: @Lix I have now fixed this too

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLines($text, $lines)
{
    $text = explode("\n", $text, $lines + 1); //The last entrie will be all lines you dont want.
    array_pop($text); //Remove the lines you didn't want.

    return implode("<br>", $text); //Implode with "<br>" to a string. (This is for a HTML page, right?)
}

echo getLines($crow->content, 2); //The first two lines of $crow->content
```

Comment: Read the OP again - he wants to return only the first two lines.

Comment: You might want to re-read you comment lines too :)  They don't make much sense after your edit...

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general answer - you can get any amount of lines using this:

```
function getLines($paragraph, $lines){
    $lineArr = explode("\n",$paragraph);
    $newParagraph = null;
    if(count($lineArr) > 0){
        for($i = 0; $i < $lines; $i++){
            if(isset($lines[$i]))
                $newParagraph .= $lines[$i];
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return $newParagraph;
}
```

you could use `echo getLines($crow->content,2);` to do what you want.